# Python TypeError in list

Tags: python, types

I'm making anagram in python
but when I call 'list'function, it doesn't work. please help.
I'm tring to change '`str`' to '`list`'
but it doesn't work. I really don't know why

[image]

```
def generate_anagram(s):
    a=s[0:len(s)-1]
    b=s[len(s)-1]
    if len(a)==1:
        return make(a,b)
    else:
        return make(generate_anagram(a),b)  

def make(s1,s2):
    list=[]
    l=len(s1)
    q=list(s1)
    w=list(s2)
    ss=""
    for i in range(l):
        if(len(q)>l):
            q.remove(w)
        q.insert(i,w)
        list+=q

    for i in range(len(list)):
        ss+=list[i]
    return ss


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print(generate_anagram("anagram"))
```

Comment: Because you've overwritten the built-in function `list()` with a variable name `list`

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
list=[]
l=len(s1)
q=list(s1)
w=list(s2)
```

is problematic because the first line will "hide" the standard function `list` by creating a local variable named `list`. This means the last two lines are not calling the `list` function of Python.

Comment: Can I ask one more? I want to make 'list[i]' to 'str' but, ss+=list[i] dosen't work.. how can I make list type to str type?

Comment: @babababam: in Python `"".join(L)` where `L` is a list of characters concatenates all of them and returns the resulting string.

Comment: Thank you! you are so kind!